# Uploading video files from iPhone library to FTP Server

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ftp

I'm a complete nooby to iPhone development, my background is in Java and C# and I'm struggling to get to grips with the syntax (string manipulation in particular). I'm working with the newest version of XCode and an iPhone with iOS 7. I'm trying to upload video and images to my web server via FTP. I downloaded SimpleFTPSample and did a bit of messing around and managed to at least get a .mov file uploaded, unfortunately all I got was a filename with zero bytes. Here is my uploadView.h :

```
    @interface uploadView : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

{
    UIImagePickerController *videoPicker;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    UIImage *image;
    NSString *testing;
    NSURL *vidPath;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;      
}

-(IBAction)takePhoto;

-(IBAction)chooseExisting;

@end
```

Here are the picking methods in my uploadView.m:

```
-(IBAction)takePhoto {

    // Changing takePhoto control to choose a video file instead
    videoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc ] init];
    videoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    videoPicker.delegate = self;
    videoPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    videoPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    videoPicker.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f;
    videoPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.movie"];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    {
        [self presentViewController:self->videoPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


}


-(IBAction)chooseExisting{

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc ] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
-(void) videoPickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)videoPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    vidPath = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
-(void) videoPickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)videoPicker
{

    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self->videoPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];    
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{


    image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    vidPath = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    testing = @"testing";
    NSLog(@"%@", testing);
    NSLog(@"%@", vidPath);
    NSLog(@"%@", testing);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

And finally the edited sender methods from SimpleFTPSample:

```
- (void)startSend:(NSString *)filePath
{
    BOOL                    success;
    NSURL *                 url;

    self.username = @"username";
    self.password = @"password";
    self.address = @"ftpaddress";
    assert(filePath != nil);
    assert( [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"png"] || [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"jpg"] || [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"MOV"] || [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"mp4"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", @"before assertion test");
    NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
    NSLog(@"%@", @"before assertion test");
    //assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);

    assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap send twice in a row!
    assert(self.fileStream == nil);         // ditto

    // First get and check the URL.

    url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:self.address];
    success = (url != nil);

    if (success) {
        // Add the last part of the file name to the end of the URL to form the final
        // URL that we're going to put to.

        url = CFBridgingRelease(
                                CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFStringRef) [filePath lastPathComponent], false)
                                );
        success = (url != nil);
    }

    // If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.

    if ( ! success) {
        self.statusLabel.text = @"Invalid URL";
    } else {

        // Open a stream for the file we're going to send.  We do not open this stream;
        // NSURLConnection will do it for us.

        self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath];
        assert(self.fileStream != nil);

        [self.fileStream open];

        // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.

        self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                               CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
                                               );
        assert(self.networkStream != nil);

        if ([self.username length] != 0) {
            success = [self.networkStream setProperty:self.username forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
            assert(success);
            success = [self.networkStream setProperty:self.password forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
            assert(success);
        }

        self.networkStream.delegate = self;
        [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.networkStream open];

        // Tell the UI we're sending.

        [self sendDidStart];
    }
}
```

And the other:

```
- (IBAction)sendAction:(UIView *)sender
{
    assert( [sender isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] );

    if ( ! self.isSending ) {
        NSString *  filePath;
        NSString *  trimmedPath;
        NSString *  testAssign;
        NSString *  absString;


        assert(sender.tag >= 0);

        absString = [vidPath absoluteString];
        trimmedPath= [absString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];
        filePath = trimmedPath;

        assert(filePath != nil);

        [self startSend:filePath];
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is too much information, my ignorance of the language and SDK is to blame. Please don't respond with comments like: "Learn more about iPhone Networking.." etc, I know I should but I'm starting a new job soon and time is running out to finish this app. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm mostly concerned with the video uploading as opposed to the images.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this code works fine and was only causing me trouble on the simulator.